# Комбинирование классов стратегий

Tags: c++, шаблон-стратегия

Начал читать Александреску, и наткнулся на следующий код в начале книги:

```
template<
    class T
    , template<class> class CheckingPolicy
    , template<class> class ThreadingModel
    , template<class> class Storage = DefaultSmartPtrStorage
    >
class SmartPtr :
    public CheckingPolicy<T>
    , public ThreadingModel<SmartPtr> {

    public:
        T *operator-> ( ) {
            typename ThreadingModel<SmartPtr>::Lock guard( *this );
            CheckingPolicy<T>::Check( mPoint );
            return mPoint;
        }

    private:
        T *mPoint;
};
```

Пытаясь разобраться как это работает, вбил это дело в свою ide и получил следующую семантическую ошибку:

> error: use of class template 'SmartPtr' requires template arguments
>   note: template is declared here

на строку

```
    , public ThreadingModel<SmartPtr> {
```

Что мне пытаются сказать я понимаю, однако не могу понять, это косяк книги, или же я допустил какую то ошибку?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, вы пытаетесь использовать в качестве параметра шаблона шаблонный класс SmartPtr, который требует параметров для спецификации шаблона. Надо либо чем-то специфицировать SmartPtr и тогда строка будет иметь вид  `public ThreadingModel<SmartPtr<что-то...>>`, либо это опечатка и там должно быть Т , вот так: `public ThreadingModel<T>`

Comment: При использовании в списке базовых классов параметры шаблона `SmartPtr` указывать обязательно, а вот внутри определения класса - уже нет.